# .htaccess causes all pages to be downloaded

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess

I added the following line to `.htaccess`:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

When I try to load any page on the side, my browser tries to DOWNLOAD the page! What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: +1 for figuring out how to do that...

Comment: A browser always downloads the page.

Answer (score 5):

Most likely; you don't have the PHP module loaded for your webserver. This means that then the server finds a application/x-httpd-php file, it passes it directly to the client instead of running it through a PHP interpretor (which would run any PHP code and output a text/html content type). Since browsers don't include PHP interpretors, they treat it as any other unknown content type, and offer to save it to disc.

Comment: and to verify this, -> try to run a normal php file with .php as a postfix

Comment: i can run .php files just fine. i'd try your test if i knew what postfix was.

Answer (score -1):

HTML documents should be served to browser as `text/html`. Change your MIME type.

```
AddType text/html .html .htm
```

If you're trying to execute HTML files as PHP, you should change the file extension to *.phtml.

- *.html - HTML content
- *.php - PHP content
- *.phtml - HTML content with embedded PHP scripts

If you're trying to force the PHP parser to work on these file types, you should be editing the `httpd.conf` file on Apache to include the `application/x-httpd-php` MIME type for those file extensions.

Comment: It seems he's trying to execute HTML documents as PHP. Ugly hack IMO. Use .php for PHP and .html for pure HTML.

Comment: PHTML is for PHP 2 (IIRC, maybe it was a different version), not for a combination of PHP and HTML. The vast majority of PHP files contain bother PHP and HTML. It makes perfect sense to run .html files through PHP if a system if moving from static HTML to PHP as it preserves existing URIs. (This made more sense before the comment it was a reply to was deleted)

Comment: @David I do not agree with that. PHTML files are defined as HTML files with embedded PHP scripts.

Comment: So.. is there any way to make this work? My server does run .php files just fine. I'm trying to save some time tonight.

Comment: As are, as mentioned before, most PHP files. .phtml is just the extension used a long long time ago. Then they switched to .php3 to make it clear that downloaded scripts needed a newer version of PHP. Then they gave up on that idea because it was still have have stuck to .php ever since.

Comment: @Michael Check my updated post: Try to make the change to the http.conf on Apache and the restart Apache.